# How to get Jhipster to return different results for authenticated and anonymous users

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster

I have developed a search API using Jhispter that returns search results (e.g., pictures) with  users favourites if they are authenticated. Now I want to return the same results but without users favourites for anonymous users. When I add the route to antMatchers in SecurityConfiguration, the API becomes unsecured. Although I am still sending the token but the security context get a null value. I guess my question is how can allow anonymous users but still have security context when sending a token for personalised results.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
        .antMatchers("/api/b2c/register")
        .antMatchers("/api/b2c/activate")
        .antMatchers("/api/b2c/reset_password/init")
        .antMatchers("/api/b2c/reset_password/finish")
        .antMatchers("/api/contact-us")
        .antMatchers("/api/search/picture")
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic().realmName("server")
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated();
}
```

Comment: [Welcome To StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page to improve this question

Comment: Can you share your SecurityConfiguration ?

Comment: Sure. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you try removing your matchers from `web.ignoring()` and add it to the ones in OAuth2ServerConfiguration with `permitAll()` access ?

Comment: I have moved the matchers from web ignoring to OAuth2ServerConfiguration and tried with both permitAll() and anonymous access. Still the same issue, but now access denied without token but works fine with token.

Comment: So basically what you want to do is apply [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ec215f79f4f73f8bb5d4b8a3ff9abe15b3335866/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L122) to unauthenticated (permitAll) endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the order of antmatchers in the OAuth2ServerConfiguration class.

.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() should come after antmatchers with permitAll() access.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your matchers from web.ignoring() and add it to the ones in OAuth2ServerConfiguration with permitAll() access

Then register the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter to be applied to your endpoint.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean customFilterRegistration(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/api/search/picture");
    registration.setName("customFilter");
    registration.setOrder(3);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still not quite sure how I can implement this and where should I add this bean. Can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: You can add this bean in any @Configuration class you want. OAuth2ServerConfiguration would be a good candidate.